# MVC access restriction for logged in users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I apologies if that has already been asked and answered but I could not find anything that could help me. Imagine a scenario where you have two clients. Both are logged in, authenticated and both are admins (for their own accounts). Each one of them can edit their products. Client_1 can edit products 1,2 and 5 and Client_2 can edit products 3,4 and 6. So in my controller I have an action:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
public ActionResult EditProduct(int productID)
{
    //Edit product here
}
```

Each client has a list of their products, they can click on the edit button that takes them to the edit page. My questions is: How to stop Client_1 from typing in

> `http://mypage/EditProduct/3` //this prduct should only be editable by Client_2

At the moment each function performs a check if user can edit this product. Do I have to write a custom logic in every function that would stop it?

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
public ActionResult EditProduct(int productID)
{
    //if(logedinUser can edit this product)
    //{
    //   Edit product here
    //}
}
```

That was fine to start with but now the number of these 'restricted functions' grew and I would like to stop repeating the same check over and over again.

Is there a better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consolidate that sort of logic with a custom AuthorizationFilter.

http://geekswithblogs.net/brians/archive/2010/07/08/implementing-a-custom-asp.net-mvc-authorization-filter.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you really have to perform a validation for this. Because when you are getting the Product from the database using the productId you can check if the userid in the where condition.

```
var result = from p in context.Products
where p.ProductId == productId && p.UserID == userid
select p;
```

If the product does not belong to the user, the query will not return any element(s). Or better yet you can grab the product without considering the userid and later check if the product returned has the userId specified. If it has a different userId may be throw a custom exception and catch it and show an error message.

You don't have to check every time for invalid access if you incorporate the logic in the data layer.