# Authorize user based on model property ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to prevent a user from being able to delete unless they created the model. (my models store the name of their creator) Right now a user clicks the "Delete" button which takes them to the delete page where they click the DeleteConfirmed button. How can I stop a user who hasn't created the model from deleting it?

I know I can get the current user's name with `Context.User.Identity.Name`

```
public ActionResult Delete(int? keyId)
{
     Task mydata = db.MyDatas.Find(keyId);
     ...
     return View(mydata);
}


[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete"), Authorize(Users = @"DOMAIN\Admin1 , DOMAIN\Bread")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int keyId)
{
     Task mydata = db.MyDatas.Find(keyId);
     ...
```

Comment: Are you talking about a generic way? The way you have right now will work. Only `Admin1` and `Bread` can execute `DeleteConfirmed`.

Comment: Right, I want to do it programatically, the code I have is just hardcoded to `admin`/`bread`

Comment: You can create a custom `Authorize` attribute or do the check manually when you enter the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest method is to use `SingleOrDefault` instead of `Find` and query based on the user at the same time:

```
Task myData = db.MyDatas.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == keyId && m.CreatedBy == User.Identity.Name)
```

Then, a user will only get a non-null thing if they created it.

Answer (score 1):

Two viable answers here:

[MVC access restriction for logged in users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25138185/mvc-access-restriction-for-logged-in-users/25138376#25138376)

Either create a custom AuthorizationFilter to encapsulate that check/logic.

Or, you can build it into your db.MyDatas.Find(keyId);

That is, add something to the effect of:

&& Creator == Context.User.Identity.Name

(If it doesn't return an object then the current user doesn't have permission to delete it.)

Answer (score 1):

You Can use ActionFilters thats what they are here for :

```
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    { 
    if((string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"]=="Delete") //check if its delete action
{
        if (db.MyDatas.Find(a=>a.ModelCreator.trim()==Context.User.Identity.Name.trim())==null)
        {
                Response.Redirect("~/Home"); //or whatever u want to give for unauthorized
        }

    }
}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass an instance of the model record that is going to be deleted into your cshtml, and then in your cshtml perform some basic logic like `{ if( Context.User.Identity.Name == model_var.user_that_created.Name){<a>Delete</a>}}`

Comment: Probably a good idea, but this doesn't prevent someone from hacking together a url or simulating a form post to the actions themselves.

Comment: Yes very true. I hadn't realized that. Thank you.